# Why does my hover keep moving away in Super Mario Maker 2?

Tags: super-mario-maker-2

**One day, I hop onto Super Mario Maker 2, and I am making a regular map.**

And then, suddenly, when I place a Goomba on the ground, and leave the hover to get another item, the hover moves after placing it. There is nothing wrong with my Switch, and this is very frequent and common. I was moving the hover with the joystick, so I tried moving it on screen, but that fell flat. The movement the hover went was up, but slowly. There are forums about the hover moving offsite, but it didn't answer my question. I don't know where the Super Mario Maker 2 support is anyway.

If possible, can anyone please tell me what is happening and why it is moving?

Comment: This sounds like the infamous JoyCon drifting issue. Assuming that's what you mean, there's not much you can do about it other than having Nintendo fix it or buying a new JoyCon. You can try recalibrating your JoyCon, but results may vary, and may not be permanent.

Answer (score 3):

The problem that you most likely have is called **Joy-Con Drift**. There isn't much you can do about this. Some small fixes you can do is to clean around the inside with a q-tip or try the calibration on both of the sticks. You can also try updating your controllers if you can.